# Like button code isn't working

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to add a like button my site. When I generate the code, and copy the javascript into my hosting thing (website tonight) I get an error: "please enter a valid javascript code"

Ok...

So instead, I try to use the iframe code, and that just disappears after I close the editing box. LOL

Here's my site: http://guitarlessonsinsandiego.com

This is the javascript code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fguitarlessonsinsandiego.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a WebSite Tonight hosting too.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/6605/adding-facebook-social-plugins-to-website-tonight

**To Add Facebook Social Plugins to WebSite Tonight**

1. Log in to your WebSite Tonight account.
2. From the Design drop-down menu, click Launch Page Designer. Your website displays in the page designer.
3. From the Page drop-down menu, select the page where you want to display the Social Plugin.
4. Click the block where you want to display the Social Plugin. Blocks are outlined in blue.
5. Click HTML. The Edit HTML window displays.
6. Paste the code in the Edit HTML window, and then click OK.
7. Re-publish your website to display the Social Plugin on your Web page.

Answer (score 1):

Think about using the 2-click variant of the like button, to support your visitors privacy: [two click facebook like](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/09/surprise-facebook-doesnt-like-privacy-countermeasures/)